# Let $f$ be a bounded function on $(a, b]$ $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$ for any $c \in (a, b]$. Prove $\lim_{x\to a} \int_{x}^{b} f(t) dt$ exists.

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, improper-integrals

I created a problem about improper integral and solved it.

Is my solution below ok?

> Let $f$ be a function on $(a, b]$ such that $f$ is bounded on $(a, b]$ and $f$ is integrable on $[c, b]$ for any $c \in (a, b]$.
> Prove that $\lim_{x\to a} \int_{x}^{b} f(t) dt$ exists.

> Let $c$ be any element in $\mathbb{R}$.
> Let $g(a)=c$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ for any $x\in (a,b]$.
> It is easy to prove that $g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.
> By a famous theorem, $G(x):=\int_{x}^{b} g(t) dt$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.
> So, $\lim_{x\to a} G(x)=\lim_{x\to a} \int_{x}^{b} g(t) dt=\lim_{x\to a} \int_{x}^{b} f(t) dt=\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt$.
> And from this proof, we can see the value of $\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt$ is independent of the value of $c$.

Comment: What theorem are you using to show that $g$ is integrable on $[a.b]$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$, where $L(f,P)$ is the lower sum of $f$ for $P$ and $U(f,P)$ is the upper sum of $f$ for $P$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Also the famous theorem which shows that $G$ is continuous is called *fundamental theorem of calculus*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Just a comment on your last sentence. A Riemann integral is independent of the values of the function at a *finite* number of points.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your useful comment.